# Create Multi-Bootable USB disk for installation Win Xp, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, usb, setup, bootable-media

Hi I need install Windows Xp, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2003 from one USB flash stick.

I google it and I found some tools such as WinSetupFromUSB but I would like have all type windows on one usb stick.

if I use for example WinSetupFromUSB I must have 3 USB stick, one for XP, second for Win 7 and
third for Win Server 2003.

It is possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Your Universal Multiboot Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) will do this.  From their page:

> YUMI (Your Universal Multiboot Installer), is the successor to MultibootISOs. It can be used to create a Multiboot USB Flash Drive containing multiple operating systems, antivirus utilities, disc cloning, diagnostic tools, and more. Contrary to MultiBootISO's which used grub to boot ISO files directly from USB, YUMI uses syslinux to boot extracted distributions stored on the USB device, and reverts to using grub to Boot Multiple ISO files from USB, if necessary.
>   Aside from a few distributions, all files are stored within the Multiboot folder, making for a nicely organized Multiboot Drive that can still be used for other storage purposes.

All you need are ISO files for each OS.

Comment: +1 Interesting tool.  Will have to try this ASAP

Comment: Be careful with the XP from USB, though. I had an issue on my netbook after I removed ubuntu where I didn't have bootloader anymore. And I figured "No big deal, I'll just put this iso on my USB and it'll be cool" but it wasn't. Ended up having to dig out my USB CD drive and using the disc.

Comment: Note this from the YUMI site: Windows XP Installer ISO will not work, as to the best of my knowledge this would require editing core proprietary files. I am open to a legal working solution.

Answer (score 1):

for 7 and better, [use the official dvd/usb download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool). The steps [here](http://kmwoley.com/blog/?p=345) would work for vista if that didn't. Not sure about xp - this seems to be the [only other method](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/111406-how-to-install-xp-from-usb/page__view__findpost__p__848669) that you haven't tried mentioned, using pe2usb

Comment: Except this only puts one image on the flash drive.  He's asking to put several on one flash drive--something any PC tech would find useful.

Comment: This is a bad answer, it should be deleted.