# creating a bootable USB drive to install windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, usb, installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Multi-Bootable USB disk for installation Win Xp, Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008](https://superuser.com/questions/310212/create-multi-bootable-usb-disk-for-installation-win-xp-windows-7-and-windows-se)

I want to create a USB which can be used as an installation media for Windows Machines
i.e. Windows XP/7/Vista Windows servers.
I tried Win2flash and USBoot both failed.